# Update cart contents via ajax request in opencart / journal

Tags: opencart2.3, journal

I am trying to update the cart contents (on any site, not the cart itself) with a journal2 theme via ajax.

I found several occurences of the following trigger in my code:

`$('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul');`

This however does not trigger the request (inspected via devTools -> network tab).

What would be the right way to update the contents of my `#cart` element via ajax?

Answer (score -1):

I did not know, that the cart instance is globally available. For anybody looking for an answer, you can just call update on the global cart object:

`cart.update();`